# How can I change collate and ctype in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
| Name      | Owner    | Encoding   | Collate                    | Ctype                      | Access privileges     |
|-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------|
| postgres  | postgres | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | <null>                |
| template0 | postgres | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres           |
|           |          |            |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres |
| template1 | postgres | UTF8       | English_United States.1252 | English_United States.1252 | =c/postgres           |
|           |          |            |                            |                            | postgres=CTc/postgres |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The value of `Collate` and `Ctype` is C.UTF-8 on Linux, but it is 1252 on Windows.

Can I change these values to C.UTF-8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot to change these values for already created databases. In this moment, when there are not other databases, the most easy solution is a) stop database, b) delete data directory, c) run manually `initdb` with options `--encoding` and `--locale` (run this command under `postgres` user). **if you have some data there, backup (with `pg_dump`) first.**

You can change these parameters when you create new database too (this is SQL command):

```
CREATE DATABASE test ENCODING='UTF8' LOCALE='C' TEMPLATE='template0';
```

Locale can be overwritten by clause `COLLATE` used in `CREATE TABLE` or `SELECT` commands.

Comment: Isn't the locale option named `LC_LOCALE`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke - no - it is LOCALE. Another option there is LC_COLLATE